# OnInfowWindowsListenerClick and IF Else

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I try to make a if statement for a GoogleMap OnInfoWindowClickListener.
But everytime I come to the else. 
And hint?

```js
Marker s780 = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
    .position(new LatLng(52.16033, 7.87964))
    .title("780")
    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.mipmap.ic_780)));

Marker s149 = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
    .position(new LatLng(52.60861, 7.99206))
    .title("149")
    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.mipmap.ic_149)));

googleMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
@Override
public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
    if (marker.equals("s780"))
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Marker 727", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    if (marker.equals("s149"))
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Marker 725", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    else
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Argument:"+marker, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: I believe you have to do == check in place of equals

Comment: Its the same, i have try this before.

Comment: I get this in Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Argument:"+marker, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Argument:com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker@3e6c7d9f

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a way for me:

```
if (marker.getTitle().equals("555 Test")) 
 { Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Marker 5", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}
```

Thank you for your hinds.

Answer (score 0):

In your code: `if (marker.equals("s780"))`, `marker` is of type `Marker`, while `"s780"` is of type `String`. Of course `equals` returns false. You should change it to something like:

```
final Marker s780 = ...
googleMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
        if (marker == s780) {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should work with the getId() function of the Marker class.

For example inside the :

```
public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(marker.getId());
    String str = builder.deleteCharAt(0).toString() ;
    int id = Integer.parseInt(str) ;
    if (id == 0)
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Marker 780 was pressed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Then you can do a simple comparison with ints which is much easier.
The ids of the markers are in order of when they were added to the map, starting by 0. So your marker s780 has the id 0 and the marker s149 has the id 1.

I hope that helped

Answer (score 0):

You just missed an `else`, so even if the first `if (s780)` was `true`, you would make a `Toast` with

> Marker 727

then check again for `if (s149)`, but eventually go inside the `else` and make a Toast with

> Argument:s780

```
   googleMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
        if (marker.equals("s780"))
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Marker 727", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        else //You missed this else
        if (marker.equals("s149")) 
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Marker 725", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        else
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Argument:"+marker, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```